# Change swf files on php page based on random order

Tags: php

I've got 4 flash files that needs to display when the php page is opened.  We don't want the page to start with the same animation every time so I need a php script to rotate them.  I was thinking of shuffling the numbers 1-4 every time the page is opened and display the swf based on that.  So if the first number in the shuffle is 4 then display swf 4.  I've got that figured out but how do I change the swf after say 1min based on the order in the shuffle array?

```
$values = range(1, 4);
shuffle($values);
foreach ($values as $value) {
$val[] = $value;
}
echo $val[0] . '<br>';
echo $val[1] . '<br>';
echo $val[2] . '<br>';
echo $val[3] . '<br>';
```

Then say the array $val[] = 4,2,1,3 and every swf animation is 1min long I need to display swf4 for 1 min, then swf2 for 1 min, then swf1 for 1 min, etc.

Comment: what is the point of that foreach? you're just doing an expensive copy operation on the array... and if you want to keep the same randomized order for a while, then stuff the shuffled array into a session and keep a timestamp flag to say when it was last shuffled.

Comment: That would be done in JavaScript, not PHP. I would write a function that swaps out the SWF source using a JavaScript timeout function. A simple array in JavaScript would hold the order of source items you will swap through.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end:

First create a shuffle function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var input = this;

    for (var i = input.length-1; i >=0; i--) {

        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
        var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

        input[randomIndex] = input[i];
        input[i] = itemAtIndex;
    }
    return input;
}
</script>
```

Then create the array and shuffle it

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tempArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
tempArray.shuffle();



//when the document is loaded display the first flash in the array
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax( "flash-" + tempArray[0] + ".php" )
.done(function(res) {
        document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
    })
});

//the function to display the second flash
function myFunction1() {
    //alert (tempArray[1]);
    $.ajax( "flash-" + tempArray[1] + ".php" )
    .done(function(res) {
        document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
    })
}
//the function to display the thirdflash
function myFunction2() {
    //alert (tempArray[2]);
    $.ajax( "flash-" + tempArray[2] + ".php" )
    .done(function(res) {
        document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
    })
}
//the function to display the fourth flash
function myFunction3() {
    //alert (tempArray[1]);
    $.ajax( "flash-" + tempArray[3] + ".php" )
    .done(function(res) {
        document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
    })
}

//let the function for the second flash execute after 15 sec
setTimeout(myFunction1, 15000);
//let the function for the second flash execute after 30 sec
setTimeout(myFunction2, 30000);
//let the function for the second flash execute after 45 sec
setTimeout(myFunction3, 60000);

</script>
```